# How to arrange 2x2 tiles depending on the plane dimensions using geometry for Modular City

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have been using a blender for a year now.

I have a specific requirement which is to arrange 2x2 tiles on a plane, and if we resize the plane it should automatically subtract or add the tile into the plane. Is it possible?

Right now you are seeing on the screenshot that some areas are filled with tiles because I did it manually. However, I want to fill the rest of the areas using geometry nodes.

[image: ScreenShot Blender Geometry Nodes]

Comment: tbh if you need this urgent i would offer money for it on another platform. But on this platform where people help for free in their spare time, my opinion is that writing  "i would like this to be answered quickly" pretty outrageous and unpolite. Normally i like answering GN questions and your questions is pretty basic - but sorry, with that sentence added you made me not to answer.

Comment: I have removed that line Chris. Now you can answer it :)

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8IE5.png build this (it's not perfect, but it gives you an idea how you can make it)

Comment: Thank you so much, bro. I'll try it. Really means a lot.

Comment: the question is lacking something… You can have a collection of tiles, and you can arrange it on a plane by using e.g. "Instance on points", and generating the points using a "Grid" node. What you show on the screenshot is some roads, but the free spaces between the roads don't seem to follow any pattern. In general, I see a lot of people trying to use Geometry Nodes to generate cities, but to be honest, it's one of the examples of what Geometry Nodes are bad at…

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZROJv.png @Chris  I appreciate your fast response. I have tried it and I have a question What if I want the cube you created in the geometry node, What if I want them to fill the plane rather than having a huge space in between? And what if the plane is not equal in length and width? 

If there are any kind of tutorials out there on the internet or YouTube please let me know. And thanks again for the previous response.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady You mean to say that if the plane dimensions are not equal, it is not possible to create a grid and instance a collection to it? Well, I know a geometry node. You must have heard about Buildify (Some say it is an addon, but it is a blender file that has geometry nodes setup.)? I mean how are they doing it?

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm not saying it's impossible, just that creating a city is a complex process and a Python addon will make it easier not just because doing anything that complex will be easier in Python than in Geonodes (basically, node systems are good because they have a low entry, it's easy to start climbing on the learning curve, but what I find to be a satisfying city builder, is where Python already overtakes) And that not considering tons of existing Python libraries with magic like AI-driven wave function collapse.

Comment: Thank you guys for helping me out and guiding me through it. I have managed to find a way and incorporate geometry nodes to build a city. It was a pretty lengthy process even after building a geo node to help me out.

The solution I found was like creating a geo node pretty much similar to an Array modifier. Since I was using the Tile system. So it didn't annoy me to align the tiles into their places. I generated a geonode that would give different houses on each index while keeping in mind the distance between each of them and making sure they are sticked to the floor. 

Thanks Again!